# Removing overlapping polygons in QGIS using attribute value?

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, overlapping-features

In QGIS, how do you remove overlapping polygons and control which polygon gets deleted? I’ve used the delete geometries tool to remove overlapping polygons within a layer but this doesn’t allow me to specify which overlapping polygon gets deleted. This is a problem because some polygons are more important than others. Can I use an attribute value to establish an order of priority when deleting overlapping polygons? I have a lot of polygons so manually removing overlap between them isn’t an option.

Answer (score 1):

I try to give you a solution using a sample data set of three polygons. Polygons have a unique ID and a PRIORITY columns.
[image]
(polygon fill is 50% transparent to see the overlapping parts).

Convert the polygons to lines (we'll use these lines to split the polygon layer)
using **Vector/Geometry Tools/Polygons to Lines...** from the menu. You'll get layer *Lines* memory layer if you don't change settings.

[image]

Split the original polygon layer by the *Lines* layer using **Processing Toolbox/Vector Overlay/Split with lines**

[image]

You get a Split layer where the overlapping areas are separated (but duplicated):

[image]

Using the **DB Manager** plug-in let's select only the necessary elements:

```
select a.geometry, a.id, a.priority from Split as a
    where st_area(a.geometry) > 0.001 and not exists (select b.id from Split as b
        where a.id <> b.id and st_contains(a.geometry, st_centroid(b.geometry)) 
        and a.priority > b.priority)
```

[image]

This *Query Layer* doesn't contain duplicates, but it should be dissolved by the original unique IDs. Using Dissolve from the Processing Toolbox we can join the areas with common IDs.

[image]

And here is the result:

[image]